# Prove that $1/2^n$ is integrable on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

How do I prove that the function defined by

\begin{align*}
 f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}   
      0 &  \text{ if } x=0\\
  1/2^n &  \text{ if } 1/2^n < x < 1/2^{n-1}
 \end{array}\right.
 \end{align*}

is integrable on $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: Which kind of integral?

Comment: They want me to use Riemann's Integrability Condition, L(f, pi) and U(f,pi)

Answer (score 1):

This is a step function; you can compute the integral explicitly as 
$$1(1)+\frac12\left(\frac12\right)+\frac14\left(\frac14\right)+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n}\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right)+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-\frac14}=\boxed{\dfrac 43}.$$
(Note the value at $0$ is irrelevant.)

**Edit:** As pointed out by @Pedro Tamaroff, this is really not a step function.  But it is the limit of a monotonically decreasing sequence of step functions, so integrable nonetheless.

Comment: but how do I prove that it is integrable

Comment: It is not a step function, since the partition is not finite.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: You are correct. But I can write it as a limit of step functions $f_k$ where $f_k$ agrees with $f$ on $[\frac1{2^k},1]$ and is constant on $(0,\frac1{2^k}]$ (necessarily equal to $\frac1{2^k}$ on that initial subinterval). Note that $f_k\rightarrow f$ monotonically.

Comment: Indeed. $f$ is an upper function.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Amended--crediting you for the observation.

Answer (score 0):

Write $A_n = (\frac{1}{2^n},\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} ]$ so that 
$$
  f
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}I_{A_n}.
$$
Then 
$$
  \int_0^1 f(x) dx
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \lambda(A_n)
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \left(\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} - \frac{1}{2^n} \right)
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \frac{1}{2^n}
< \infty.
$$
(Here $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure).